# How to dynamicly group columns, based on the month VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I am writing a code to hide the data passed the **current month** (IntMonth). So for example if 8 is selected in the IntMonth, the 9th month until the 12th should be hidden. i have tried different things but i can not manage to make a consistent macro that does exactly this. To be fair, I am quite new to VBA.

***Coding Goal***

- The code should hide and group all months passed the current one, filled in as IntMonth. So if 8 is filled in for IntMonth, the code should group and hide month 9-12 and it should be able to repeat this process when the month will be manually adjusted
- starting at the 5th sheet all the way to the 100th sheet
- The coding should skip sheets starting with "CC"

Below the code i wrote so far, this code has the following defects

***Current Coding errors***

- now the code does not include the last sheet
- The Coding should stop when in rans into the word "End" (Column N ) in row 5 but always includes the next column (Colomn T)
- The code only works if you run it twice

[Colomn lay-out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu6LE.jpg)

```
            Sub Groeperen()


            '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Update variables from this point

            Dim IntMonth As Integer, rData As Range, rCel As Range, x As Integer, i As Long

              IntMonth = Range("IntMonth")

            '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Define sheetnumber where to start running the macro (as i)
                x = 5

            '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Don't change anything after this point
            '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

             Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            'ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

            For i = x To Worksheets.Count
                Worksheets(i).Select
                If Right(ActiveSheet.Name, 2) <> "CC" Then

                    Range("C5").Select
                    Set rData = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight))


                    Range(Columns("A"), Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Selection.Columns.Ungroup
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Range("A1").Select
                        For Each rCel In rData
                            If rCel >= IntMonth Then
                                Columns(rCel.Column).Group
                                rCel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            Else
                                If rCel = "End" Then Stop
                            End If
                        Next 'rCel


                End If 'Right(Sheets(i).Name, 2) <> "CC"

            Next 'i

              Application.ScreenUpdating = True

            End Sub
```

Comment: `Stop` set a breakpoint in code, use `Exit For` to end the `For` loop early

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` does not apply only to the next line, but to the whole code following and hide errors. Use `On Error Goto 0`to restore normal behavior once hiding is not needed anymore.

Comment: In your dialog you stated you only want sheets STARTING with "CC" but your code is looking for sheets ENDING with "CC".  If you want the first two letters then instead of `Right`, use `Left`.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up the `For Next` block and everything inside it based on what you wrote, tweaking the code to accomplish what you are after. I fixed the syntax that was wrong, and also the logic. You were very close to being there, you just have a little bit of logic off.

```
For i = x To Worksheets.Count

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(i)

    With ws

        If Left(.Name, 2) <> "CC" Then

            .Activate

            Set rData = .Range(.Range("C5"), .Range("N5")) 'can set to N5 since it's constant and it will stop before it gets to "End"
            With .Range(.Range("A5").EntireColumn, .Range("N5").End(xlToRight))
                On Error Resume Next
                .Columns.Ungroup
                On Error GoTo 0
                .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End With

            For Each rCel In rData
                If rCel >= IntMonth Then
                    .Columns(rCel.Column).Group
                    rCel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next 'rCel

        End If 'Left(ws.Name, 2) <> "CC" Then

    End With

Next 'i
```